# Squaring particular elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an input list as follows:

```
input =[[7.842, 2], 
       [4.6861, 4], 
       [9.128, 5]]
```

I want to square the second attribute of each row:

```
Output =[[7.842, 4], 
        [4.6861, 16], 
        [9.128, 25]]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this, this will modify the array in place

```
test = np.array([[7.842, 2], 
       [4.6861, 4], 
       [9.128, 5]])

test[:,1] **= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-numpy version of this is:

```py
>>> output_list = [[x[0], x[1] ** 2] for x in input_list]
[[7.842, 4], [4.6861, 16], [9.128, 25]]
```